# Network Response Timed Out when Using Expo on ubuntu

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to run My react-native application, I'm running it on android emulator and my phone HUAWEI Y5 and same thing happens. I was working on it fine a few days ago but suddenly this error keeps coming up

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something blocking connection suddenly ? Maybe router.

Try:

> expo start --tunnel